# python-socket is already closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, centos, centos7

I want to subscribe to a websocket to get stream of data. to do so, I just created a fresh `Centos 7` server, then installed firewalld and openned ports 80/tcp and 443/tcp. now when I run my python bot, it crashes with the following error:

```
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: socket is already closed.
```

**but when I run the same code on another server (`Centos 8 with probably different configurations`) it runs without this error.** so the source of problem is not the code, and probably something related to OS level, or ports. how to solve the issue, or even detect the causing root?

code:

```
from time import sleep
from pybit import usdt_perpetual
ws_linear = usdt_perpetual.WebSocket(
test=False,
ping_interval=30,
ping_timeout=10,
domain="bybit")

def handle_message(msg):
print(msg)

ws_linear.kline_stream(
handle_message, "DOTUSDT", "D")

while True:
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Without seeing the code it's difficult for us to tell what may be the source of the problem.

Comment: @larsks updated the question with code. it just uses the Bybit exchange library, so nothing special!

Comment: experiencing the same issue with pybit